# How to load a text file from a runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

If i have a project which has a text file inside of it and i want to be able to read this text file which will be stored in my runnable jar then how can i do this? Currently i have a setup like this

```
public void someMethod()
{
    File f = new File("aFileInEclipseResourcesFolder.txt");

    doSomethingWithFile(f);
}

private void doSomethingWithFile(File f)
{
    //print the data in the file;
}
```

The issue is the application cant locate the file if i use this approach but if i use a hard coded path to the file then it works. I know you can use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` but this wont allow me to get the already written file in to a file object without rewriting it again, or is this assumption incorrect?

Regards

Comment: Have you tried putting a "./aFileinEclipse.txt"? The "./" makes it search the current directory. AKA where the .jar is located.

Comment: The problem is that the jar file is used as an addon by another application so when i print the working directory it prints the folder the other application uses, is that correct?

Comment: I'll admit that in that case, I'm not sure where it would designate the current directory. But, can't you just place the .txt file in the directory of the main program then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use getResourceAsStream() you want

```
public URL getResource(String name)
```

the URL will give you the path to the resource and you can create a File object from that.

Comment: this is semi correct, but it still looks in the wrong place for the file. Using the method above the programme looks in the folder where the jar file resides. If i print the file path i get `file:/c:/....../jarFileName!/nameOfTextFile.txt` is this correct?

Comment: Yes that should be the correct path for the file. I have used this method and created a File object from the URL before.

Answer (score 1):

The getResourceAsStream delivers an InputStream you can use, just as a FileInputStream. You then can use:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("a/b/c/aFileInEclipseResourcesFolder.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")); // Or "Cp1252"?
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem around a year ago the only solution I found was finding the location of the jar file (which is actually just a zip file), going through it and finding the file I wanted.

There are better methods around but they never worked for me (go figure), so keep this as a last resort.